# Response not defined in Scrapy parse function

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I am trying to write a Scrapy spider in combination with Selenium to access some JavaScript content on the page I am scraping. I have managed to open the page using Selenium and waiting until the content appears. Now I want to construct a Scrapy `TextResponse` from the completely loaded page. My code looks like this (I removed the URLs and selector strings, they don't matter):

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import TextResponse 
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class EexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "eex"
    allowed_domain = ["..."]
    start_urls = ["..."]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '...')))

        # this is where things go wrong
        print response.url # prints the correct url
        text_response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
        # NameError: name 'response' is not defined
```

When I run the crawler I get the error `NameError: name 'response' is not defined` in the line where I am calling the `TextResponse` constructor. Strangely, I am able to successfully print `response.url` in the line before.

Does anybody know why this could be the case?

P.S. Let me know if you want to see the stack trace, I just didn't want to make the question appear even longer.

*Disclaimer:* I'm a total Python noob ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the line containing `TextResponse` is indented properly.

For instance, if I have the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.http import TextResponse 
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class EexSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "eex"
    allowed_domain = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://google.com"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.driver.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

    text_response = TextResponse(url=response.url, body=self.driver.page_source, encoding='utf-8')
```

I'm getting the exact same error:

> NameError: name 'response' is not defined

Comment: I mixed tabs and spaces... that's what you get for copying code from StackOverflow. Thanks!